# "Get in" or "Get into the car"

Tags: grammar

*Get in* or *get into the car*: Which is correct or what is the difference between them?

Comment: AmE - we say *get in*. Into = in + to. Once you're in, there's not a lot of space to go *to*, so it's just, get in, front or back. Sounds gruff. :(

Comment: No. _Into_ implies {from [the outside] to [the inside]} – a single directional transformation – ie {AB}, not {A} then {B}. Although _in_ is used as an adverb (some would probably claim 'intransitive preposition') as well as a preposition, _into_ isn't. So 'Get into the car' is shortened to 'Get in', just as 'Get in the car' is.

Comment: It's probably safest to say that *get into the car* is the "correct" version if one subscribes to prescriptive grammar following on Lowth and Murray, but that to use it in much of the North American vernacular, at least, would either be hypercorrection or mark one as a non-native speaker. The real grammar of English is not at all clear-cut or universal.

Comment: @Susan We do say things like *I need to get into the car, but I left the clicker in the office*. I would agree that *get into* sounds stiff in AmE when used as an imperative, though in order to be *gruff*, I would say *get yourself into the car*.

Answer (score 3):

Both seems to be correct, in the context at least.

Get in and into the car both tells you to go towards the inside of the car. However, from my experience "get in" is usually merely a shorthand for "get into the car", or spoken while you are inside the car to someone outside the car. STILL, both can be used interchangeably

Answer (score 1):

As Raestloz said, both are correct, and are mostly used in different contexts.

Based on my experience,
"Get into the Car" is used, when both of you are outside the car . (Ex.: Get into the car, I will go and get some things which I forgot)

"Get In" is used when you are inside the car, and the other person is still waiting outside.(Ex.: What are you waiting for, get in !)

Answer (score 0):

I think we use "get into" the car when someone(from outside) asks or suggests to enter the car. And "get in" is used by someone inside to ask someone (outside) enter the Car. Examples. Come on, let's get into the car. Hello friend! who are you waiting for? Get in please. It's too late.

Answer (score 0):

We use **Get into/Get* out of* when we are talking about the smaller modes of transportation, such as - taxis, cars, vans, canoes, small boats, etc.

We use *Get on/Get off* when we talk about the bigger modes of transportation, such as  - trams, trains, buses, planes, ships, animals and bicycles (camels, horses, etc).

https://www.english-at-home.com/transport-vocabulary/